# My service is returning 200 status code, but my MVC controller IsSuccessStatusCode returns FALSE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a web service developed in .NET, in a Web API, which has a controller that executes the registration of new users. Once the record is complete, it returns an `HttpActionResult` with `HttpStatusCode` of 200 (OK), but my project controller in MVC interprets it as 500 (Internal Server Error). I've been doing this for hours and I can not find the reason. It is not an error in the tasks that run behind the controller, because `try / catch` would throw the error, which does not happen. It is the only method of the service controller that is giving me these problems. Any idea why it may be happening?

Here's my Web API controller's method (sender):

```
public IHttpActionResult RegisterAttendee(ParticipantDTO participantDto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();
    int result = _context.RegisterParticipant(participantDto);
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

And here's my MVC controller's method (receiver):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterParticipant(RegisterIndexBaseVm attendee)
    {
        if (attendee == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            attendee.EventId = Int32.Parse(Session["id"].ToString());
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync("Register/RegisterAttendee", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Mapper.ToParticipant(attendee)), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(EmpResponse);
                    if (result == 0)
                        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    else
                        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

Thanks for the support

Comment: You're sure `RegisterAttendee` makes it to the `return` statement and  doesn't throw an Exception? Incidentally, MVC controllers support `async` so there is no need (and you should not) to block with `.Result`.

Comment: I'd check the value of `participantDto` in `RegisterAttendee` since that's **one** of the places where you can `return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest`

Comment: Thanks, @Crowcoder . I'm completely sure. I followed the process step by step and completed all the steps in the backend. Do you think the problem is not to make the asynchronous call?

Comment: @AdolfoF.IbarraLandeo no, I don't think that is the reason for the 500 server error, it is just wasteful for the system and can deadlock if you were to refactor your calling code in certain ways.

Comment: @Jimenemex, I'm catching all the errors in the backend methods, but none is thrown, it's all within a Try

Comment: @Crowcoder, thanks. I changed the method to async for your recommendation. The entry is updated with the same problem.

Comment: @AdolfoF.IbarraLandeo you still have another `.Result` in there.

Comment: @AdolfoF.IbarraLandeo step through the code and see exactly what status code is returned.

Comment: thanks @Nkosi, when I make the call, the response is sent as `HttpStatusCode.OK`, but `HttpResponseMessage` is receiving it as Internal Server Error.

Comment: Why does it look like the two actions are calling each other

Comment: @Nkosi Hahaha I'm using the same names, but `_context` points to an interface registered in another layer of the service...

Comment: @AdolfoF.IbarraLandeo Update Web API to `return Ok(result);`

Comment: @Nkosi, It was with `return Ok(result);` before putting it as it is currently. In both cases it gave a bad result... All the other methods I have are with `return Ok(result)', but this is the only one that gave me problems.